# How to count messages with different or indifferent field values with graylog?

Tags: graylog2, graylog, gelf

I'm using graylog to visualize some http request data. I would like to have a widget which shows how many different IPv4 addresses have been accessing a website within the given time range.

The IPv4 address gets saved within a log entry in the field called "ip". See screenshot. [image: Graylog message with ip field]

How can i realize that? The next target will be to create a widget which shows how many messages per ip address got logged within the given time range.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your actual use case, you can either use "Field Statistics" (cardinality is the number of unique values for that field) or "Quick Values" on the message field containing the IP address.

[image: Field Statistics and Quick Values example]